# Select one set of duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server, how do I select only one "set" of relationships? To explain, here is an example. Also if you can help me figure out how to "say" this problem to make it more google-able, that would be stellar. For example, the single table contains two identical, inverted rows.

```
CREATE TABLE #A (
    EmployeeID INT,
    EmployeeName NVARCHAR(100),
    CoworkerID INT,
    CoworkerName NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #A VALUES (1, 'Alice', 2, 'Bob')
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (2, 'Bob', 1, 'Alice')
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (3, 'Charlie', 4, 'Dan')
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (4, 'Dan', 3, 'Charlie')

SELECT *
FROM #A

// THIS IS WHAT WE WANT TO PROGRAMATICALLY DETERMINE - which ID's to keep and which to delete.

DELETE FROM #A WHERE EmployeeID = 2
DELETE FROM #A WHERE EmployeeID = 4

SELECT *
FROM #A
```

So, the net result of the final query is:

```
|------------|---------------|-------------|--------------|
| EmployeeID | EmployeeName  | CoworkerID  | CoworkerName |
|------------|---------------|-------------|--------------|
|      1     |    Alice      |     2       |     Bob      |
|------------|---------------|-------------|--------------|
|      3     |    Charlie    |     4       |     Dan      |
|------------|---------------|-------------|--------------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM #A 
WHERE #A.EmployeeID > #a.CoworkerID
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #A A2
       where a2.CoworkerID = #A.EmployeeID
       and a2.employeeID = #a.coworkerID)
```

[***See SqlFiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9ba2c/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

This will only delete those with a circular reference.  If you have more complex chains, this will not affect them.

```
DELETE a
FROM #A a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM #A t 
    WHERE t.CoworkerID = a.EmployeeID
        AND  t.EmployeeID < a.EmployeeID
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 WITH t2CTE AS  
    (  
       SELECT*, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY employeename ORDER BY employeename) as counter1  
       FROM #a
    )  
    DELETE FROM t2CTE WHERE counter1 >1
```